# Iframe load a javascript which is loaded in parent page bu donot load from disk cache

Tags: javascript, iframe, no-cache

I have a page which contains 4 Iframe, and all the pages add the same javascript. When the page loaded, I found the same javascript loaded from server 5 times. And then I set all Iframes loads when the javascript is loaded in the parent page, but get the same results, WHY?

- The Code of the parent page:

  ```
  <html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
      <iframe></iframe>
      <iframe></iframe>
      <iframe></iframe>
      <iframe></iframe>
  </body>
  <script>
      var newScript = document.createElement("script");
      newScript.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js";

      var srcs = ["html1.html", "html2.html", "html3.html", "html4.html"];
      document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD").item(0).appendChild(newScript);
      newScript.onload = newScript.onreadystatechange = function () {
          console.log("jquery.min.js loaded");
          var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
          for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
              var id = i;
              iframes[id].src = srcs[id];
          }
      }
      console.log("init");
  </script>

  </html>
  ```
- The code in all iframe page:

  ```
  <html>

  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
      <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
      <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="Cache" content="no-cache">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      html1
  </body>

  </html>
  ```
- Image:
  Network of DevTool:

  [image]

  [image]

Comment: It is because, on your developer tools window, you have enabled the 'Disable Cache' option.

Comment: It is not, and I add another Image with 'Disable Cache' option

Answer (score 0):

An iframe has different context. Its like a separate browser tab or window. So its quite normal I think.

Comment: But why An frame could not load Javascript which has been loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "iframe to load the javascript which has been loaded", but if you mean that you want to load the script once in the parent window and use it in the iframes, then the answer is you cant and this is due to security constraints in the browser I think.

Comment: Yeap, I meant that. Where can I get some document about what you said ' due to security'?

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#security-nav probably this might help

Comment: Thinks，@factor5